# How to avoid repeated calls of class method when it only needs to be executed once

Tags: python, performance, class, oop

Below is a snippet where I have lengthy calculation which I only want to perform once - because it takes a long time. I need to call this calculation repeatedly in other methods (in this example, only one - `do_something_with_my_value`).

Is there a way I can make `my_value` execute only once, and store the value down for the purposes of using it in `do_something_with_my_value`?

I could bind the return value of `my_value` in the function itself by manually setting a class attribute. But this would require the type hint to return `None`.

```
from typing import List


class Example:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass

    def my_value(self) -> int:
        """Lenghthy calcultion, and so don't want to put in __init__"""
        return 1

    def do_something_with_my_value(self) -> List[int]:
        """Repeatedly uses my_value."""
        return [x + self.my_value() for x in range(1, 1000)]
```

I'm wondering if there's a "pythonic" design that avoid repeatedly doing a lengthy calculation as in the snippet above.

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `my_value` never changes throughout the life-cycle of your class then the [`functools.cached_property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cached_property) decorator is ideal:

```
from functools import cached_property

class Example:

    @cached_property
    def my_value(self) -> int:
        """Lengthy calculation goes here"""
        return 1

    def do_something_with_my_value(self) -> list[int]:
        """Note how my_value is accessed as a property rather than a function call"""
        return [x + self.my_value for x in range(1, 1000)]
```

Answer (score 1):

`my_value` should probably be a property which can track when and if the calculation has been made yet.

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self):
        self._actual_value: Optional[int] = None

    @property
    def my_value(self) -> int:
        if self._actual_value is None:
            self._actual_value = 1

        return self._actual_value

    def do_something_with_my_value(self) -> list[int]:
        return [x + self.my_value for x in range(1, 1000)]
```

Most type checkers should be able to narrow the type of `self._actual_value` to `int` when returning its value from `my_value`'s getter.